# Trello Notifications to a Secondary email Address

Tags: trello, email, notifications

Getting used to Trello but can't find out how to use more than one email address. I know I can add a secondary email to my account but how can I get some cards / boards to notify me on that address and others to the primary? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add multiple email addresses on trello for login and communication purposes but there can only be one primary id

You can check the same here: http://help.trello.com/article/773-adding-account-credentials

Comment: Yep. I'd got that far. So you can only get notifications on one email address for every board or card? My problem is that working as a white label designer my clients often give me an email address from their company so I appear to belong to their team. So if I use Trello for all my projects with other clients, notifications from their boards will be coming to an email account which belongs to the first client making it not totally under my control and not confidential.

Comment: Ah, get it. Then why don't you tell every client to create a new email and you also create multiple accounts?

Comment: Because I wanted Trello to organise my time over all projects. Having multiple accounts would require logging in and out constantly to see all the projects I'm working on and I wouldn't be able to put them all side-by side on one screen like I need to. I'd spend more time organising Trello than working, which is a bit counter-productive.

Comment: Completely agree, but let's hope they will come up with the feature soon